# I can import most of Scikitlearn using miniconda, but cannot get load_digits

Tags: numpy, graph, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I only have miniconda, as i was unable to download anaconda in full, but I am able to import sklearn and hundreds of other programs normally.
However, when I try and import the load_digits part, as follows

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
print(digits['DESCR'])
```

I get this error message

```
     69     # We are not importing the rest of scikit-learn during the build
     70     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
```

which prevents me from importing this specific graph. The same problem happens with GaussianProcessRegressor but most np forms of graphs import normally. Can someone explain what the problem is here?

I get the error message rather than the graphs automatically uploading like they should

Comment: How exactly did you install Scikit-Learn?

Answer (score 0):

It looks [from the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/__init__.py#L72-L74) as if this is something that can only happen while the package is being built. But if you are simply installing with `conda` then perhaps there's a bug in whatever version you have. Try switching to another version, e.g. (depending on your current version) with

```
conda install sklearn=1.3.1
```

And see if that fixes it.